# Changing Owner within LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm finding that it's impossible to invoke a quick action from within an LWC and it also that `lightning-input-field` does not support `OwnerId`.

Does anyone know of a workaround that would allow changing an `Owner` on a custom object from within an LWC?

I'm thinking I may be able to query for users with Apex and loading them up into a `lightning-combobox` but that might not be scalable for the number of potential users but that will probably not scale.

For a little more context: we're using LWC to create a page from which our end users can perform all their business functions in one page, rather than clicking through many objects to achieve the same functionality. Our end users would like to be able to change the owner of objects within this page without navigating to that particular record's page itself.

Comment: Can you explain first what your business goal is?

Comment: Thank you @zaitsman. I edited the question to add another explanatory paragraph